# Count all sub-arrays having sum divisible by k

Tags: python, algorithm

While I was studying for interviews, I found this question and solution on GeeksForGeeks, but don't understand the solution.

What it says is

```
Let there be a subarray (i, j) whose sum is divisible by k
  sum(i, j) = sum(0, j) - sum(0, i-1)
```

> Sum for any subarray can be written as q*k + rem where q  is a
>   quotient and rem is remainder Thus,

```
    sum(i, j) = (q1 * k + rem1) - (q2 * k + rem2)
    sum(i, j) = (q1 - q2)k + rem1-rem2
```

> We see, for sum(i, j) i.e. for sum of any subarray to be
>   divisible by k, the RHS should also be divisible by k.
>   (q1 - q2)k is obviously divisible by k, for (rem1-rem2) to 
>   follow the same, rem1 = rem2 where

```
    rem1 = Sum of subarray (0, j) % k
    rem2 = Sum of subarray (0, i-1) % k
```

First of all, I don't get what `q1` and `q2` indicate.

```
def subCount(arr, n, k): 

    # create auxiliary hash 
    # array to count frequency 
    # of remainders 
    mod =[] 
    for i in range(k + 1): 
        mod.append(0) 

    cumSum = 0
    for i in range(n): 
        cumSum = cumSum + arr[i] 

        mod[((cumSum % k)+k)% k]= mod[((cumSum % k)+k)% k] + 1


    result = 0  # Initialize result 

    # Traverse mod[] 
    for i in range(k): 

        if (mod[i] > 1): 
            result = result + (mod[i]*(mod[i]-1))//2

    result = result + mod[0] 

    return result
```

And in this solution code, I don't get the role of `mod`. What is the effect of incrementing the cound of `((cumSum % k)+k)% k`th array?

It would be great if this can be explained step by step easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with integer modulo/remainder operation?

```
 7 modulo 3 = 1 because  
 7 = 2 * 3 + 1
 compare
 N % M = r 
 because N might be represented as
 N = q * M + r
 here r is remainder and q is result of integer division like
 7 // 3 = 2
```

For modulo `k` there might be `k` distinct remainders `0..k-1`

`mod` array contains counters for every possible remainder. When remainder for every subrange sum is calculated, corresponding counter is incremented, so resulting `mod` array data looks like `[3,2,5,0,7]` three zero remainders, two remainders are equal to 1...